# Why is my drop-down navbar not getting displayed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a left aside which is `260px` wide and a right aside which is `260px` wide. My center div is fluid `100%` width.

[image]

On the click of the right arrow, i want to have a `dropdown` of the same width of the center div container. Below is my code and `fiddle`, but it seems the drop-down is not working at all.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">    
   <div class="row">
    <div class="leftBox pull-left" href="#">

    </div>
    <div class="rightBox pull-right" href="#">
      Right Div
    </div>
     <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
           <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
               <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vBjwC

Comment: your link is not working, it says application error

Comment: post your work on jsfiddle, and provide the link

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt: Have put a working version, bootply seems to be down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the drop down is working, but you are using `collapse` class with it, so it is already in the collapsed state..

And:
adding this in js:

```
function fun(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('nav-collapse')[0].classList.remove('collapse');
}
```

and this in css:

```
.nav-collapse{width:60%; float:left;}
```

does make things work. Try it on.